# Increasing the available memory to R process in Unix shell

Tags: r

I run R process on my Unix OS which has 16 GB RAM. I am running an R session in which I am doing the below operation:

I import a csv file which is around 350 MB in size into a data frame. 
Then I run an operation on the data frame created above to select the top n products for each unique group.

But, when I check the amount of memory this R session takes, it shows around 90% and then automatically the session gets killed. I am not much aware about the memory management in R on unix.
Because, my system's OS has 16 GB RAM and my R session could have taken a maximum of 700 MB(350 MB for the imported CSV and 350 MB for the new data frame being created), then how is it possible that it uses 90% memory of the system and gets killed. Is there some default limit to the memory allocated to R process in Unix? If yes, can it be increased. Can anyone please suggest. I went through many posts similar to this but could not find any solution.

Comment: When your method creates e.g. a matrix of pairwise comparisons, this can easily flood your memory. So, without knowing exactly how your method works, it's difficult to know. My guess is that it creates a matrix that is larger than you expect it to be...

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: My data frame created from importing csv is like below:
a   b   c
1   2   .1
1   3   .45
1   4   .22
3   2   .76
3   1   .45
....

Then I create another data frame from above to select top 2 rows for each unique value of column a based on maximum values of column c using the below function.

d<-ddply(data_frame, "a", function(df) df[1:min(nrow(df), 2),])

Could you please suggest now what could be happening. Also,
csv file imported into a data frame has around 3.5 lacks of unique values of column a

Comment: How much RAM did it take up when you tested your code on a smaller example? You did try it on a smaller example didn't you? Because there's no way you can check code for correctness with millions of rows and columns. Make smaller examples, plot example size against RAM used up.

Comment: Size of a CSV file may have no bearing on the size needed to store it as floating point numbers. "0,0,0,0" takes 7 bytes in a CSV and 32 once read into RAM as 8-byte precision floats. Conversely "3.14159267833,2.5445354535,3.334234343" takes about 40 bytes in a CSV and 24 in RAM. Your 350MB is meaningless in this context. How many rows, how many columns, what kind of data?

Answer (score 4):

You didn't say what Unix flavour you have, and whether it is 32 or 64 bit. That matters.

As a first test, try to allocate the amount of memory you think you should have, eg something like

```
 m <- rep(NA, 0.8 * 16 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 / 8)
```

or

```
 m <- matrix(NA, 0.8 * 16 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 / 8, 1)
```

for 16 gb, with each element being 8 bytes, and we're asking for 80% of the total to not bring the system down.

Then, once you know how much memory you can get, do as Daniel suggested and think your 
methods through to know how much they'd take.